# npm: Why does misspelling like npm urn work?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was deploying an SPA to a production server and accidentally entered `npm urn build` in the command shell. I noticed my typo and expected npm will throw an error but it built the project anyway.

Seems like npm developers made some preparation for mistakes like this one. What's the reason/history behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the other answers seem to be referring to the edit distance-based "did you mean" function, but npm [has some manual corrections built in](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/lib/utils/cmd-list.js). These corrections include changing camelCase to kebab-case, aliasing `urn` to `run`, and a lot more aliases.

Answer (score 5):

NPM uses the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm to find similar commands. See https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/lib/utils/did-you-mean.js.

Implemented on Jun 28, 2018. See https://github.com/npm/cli/commits/latest/lib/utils/did-you-mean.js.

Comment: Well, don't you think too much flexibility like this can cause unexpected errors and problems?

Comment: And, it didn't fail, it ran without saying anything. I've seen typo suggestions but this one told me nothing.

Comment: @bravemaster I agree this is an opinionated decision.

Comment: @bravemaster If you believe this behavior is a bug, feel free to submit an issue on https://github.com/npm/cli/issues.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is indended by npm so as to minimize errors.
For instance

```
npm tes runs as npm test.
```

Seems like there is significant machine learning under the hood

Comment: @axiac Can this minimize errors? I'm afraid it'd rather increase the chance.

Comment: @linda93 I agree. Although it saved me some time a couple of times, I don't think it's healthy that NPM just "assumes" intention.